# CoreNLP 3.6 maven central release

Tags: stanford-nlp

According to http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html, the latest version of coreNLP should be available in maven central "several days" after available in the download page. In https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/history.html, I can see that 3.6 went out in early december.

When can I expect a maven central release of CoreNLP 3.6?

Comment: While this question might be interesting for NLP-interested developers, it is a bit unsuited to StOF as nobody has a magic oracle for predictions on the release schedules or mirroring strategies of projects like stanford-nlp. Maybe, this question should be asked on the Mailing-/Dev-Lists of the project owners? A valid answer would be (at least somehow): "Somewhere near in the future". Would you be willing/able to accept such an answer provided to you?

Comment: Sure, it is a legitimate answer. I just used the channel that was indicated in the project page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maven release of 3.6.0 should be within the next week.